# SVG background text is truncated in Safari and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, safari

I am trying to render a svg image animated in my page. Image and text work fine but the background text is truncated when visualized in Safari and Chrome.

The code I used in my html is the following

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1106px" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 1106 558" enable-background="new 0 0 1106 558" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin none">
  <g id="light_1">
       <rect x="334" y="256" fill="#B60C05" width="726" height="58"/>
       <text transform="matrix(1.5 0 0 1 345 301)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Open Sans'" font-size="50" letter-spacing="3.333">SCULTURE - DESIGN</text>
  </g>
  <g id="light_3">
      <text transform="matrix(1.1 0 0 1 500 239)" fill="#B60C05" font-family="Work Sans" font-size="36" letter-spacing="1.5" font-weight="300">ALESSANDRA POLITI PAGNONI</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elenapoliti/pfu85omt/3/) as an example (check how it appears if opened in Firefox or in Safari/Chrome) with css style.

Anyone can help me in fixing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on browsers to render text - especially with custom fonts - exactly the same is not a good idea.  The best solution to your problem is to not use `<text>` elements, and instead convert all your text to paths (outlines). That way all the browsers are guaranteed to display your text exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks I will try what you suggested